# Image wont float to the right properly in IE7

Tags: css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

For some reason in this page ( link removed ) the images in one of the boxes will not float right to the text properly on IE7. I've been looking for 2 days and I have no idea why this happens. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

internet explorer needs a defined width on each floating element for calculate.

```
.csc-textpic-imagewrap{
 width:120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess you place images after elements floated left. Try placing them at first.

Comment: That is dont automatically by the CMS, and it's quite hard to change. But in this case the image goes first and is floated right, and the text comes later and is NOT floated. Notice how image-wrapper is floated right, but for some reason it takes all the width of the box in ie7. I dont get why...

Comment: to .csc-textpic-single-image set float: none